# Nested form validation in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following code:

```
<%= form_with(model: [@lawsuit, @lawsuit.suits.build]) do |f| %>

  <fieldset>
    <legend>New Suit</legend>
  </fieldset>
  <br />
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :claim %>
    <%= f.text_field :claim, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Name' %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :sentence %>
    <%= f.text_area :sentence, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Sentence' %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :result %>
    <%= f.select(:result, [['Not Favorable', false], ['Favorable', true]], {}, {class: 'form-control'}) %>
  </div>

  <%= button_tag type: 'submit', class: "btn btn-primary float-right" do %>
    <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    Create
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

How can I show the list of errors of the suit (which is a nested attribute of @lawsuit) and show it's errors on the screen ? I have already done the validations on the model. The model is like that:

```
class Suit < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :lawsuit

  validates_presence_of :claim, :sentence
end
```

My controllers are like below.

The process start in lawsuit controller. There I build the @suit (which is used in the form).

Suit controller:

```
class SuitsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_suit, only: [:show]

  def new
  end

  def create
    Rails.logger.info "=====================SUIT CREATION"
    @lawsuit = Lawsuit.find(params[:lawsuit_id])
    @suit = @lawsuit.suits.build(suit_params)
    Rails.logger.info "AISHA #{@suit.errors.any?}"
    # @suit = @lawsuit.suits.new(suit_params)

    if @suit.save
      flash[:notice] = "Suit created successfully"
      redirect_to lawsuit_path(@lawsuit)
    else
      Rails.logger.info "AISHA #{@suit.valid?}"
      flash[:alert] = "Something went wrong"
      redirect_to lawsuit_path(@lawsuit)
    end
  end
```

Lawsuit Controller

```
class LawsuitsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_lawsuit, only: [:show]

  def index
      @lawsuits = Lawsuit.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 8)
    end

    def show
        begin
            @blob = Lawsuit.get_blob_for_document(@lawsuit.document_number)[1]
        rescue
            @blob = "Cannot load document!"
            flash[:error] = "Cannot load document!"
        end

        @lawsuit = Lawsuit.find(params[:id])
        @suit = @lawsuit.suits.build
    end

    private
        def set_lawsuit
            @lawsuit = Lawsuit.find(params[:id])
        end

        def lawsuit_params
            params.require(:lawsuit).permit(:document_number, :region, :court, :noted)
        end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Modify view as follows

```
<%= form_with(model: [:lawsuit, @suit]) do |f| %>

  <fieldset>
    <legend>New Suit</legend>
  </fieldset>
  <br />

  <% if @suit.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2>
        <%= pluralize(@suit.errors.count, "error") %>
        <%= "prohibited this suit from being saved:" %>
      </h2>
      <ul></ul>
      <% @suit.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li>
          <%= message %>
        </li>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  <% end %>


  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :claim %>
    <%= f.text_field :claim, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Name' %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :sentence %>
    <%= f.text_area :sentence, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Sentence' %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :result %>
    <%= f.select(:result, [['Not Favorable', false], ['Favorable', true]], {}, {class: 'form-control'}) %>
  </div>

  <%= button_tag type: 'submit', class: "btn btn-primary float-right" do %>
    <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    Create
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

note you should build `@suit` object from controller action first

```
@suit = @lawsuit.suits.build
```

and you controller should be

```
class SuitsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_suit, only: [:show]

  def new
  end

  def create

    @lawsuit = Lawsuit.find(params[:lawsuit_id])
    @suit = @lawsuit.suits.build(suit_params)

    if @suit.save
      flash[:notice] = "Suit created successfully"
      redirect_to lawsuit_path(@lawsuit)
    else
      render :form
    end
  end
```

Or

If you want to display flash message then you should write following code on view

```
<% flash.each do |key, value| %>
  <div class="alert alert-<%= key %>"><%= value %></div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: It's weird because if I build a suit on rails console and do like suit = Lawsuit.last.suits.build and check if there's any error, the result is true.

Comment: I think it's something related to redirect.